# Java heap size - will this work?

Tags: java, heap-memory

I try this with NetBeans desktop application template - increasing heapsize (to 512 MiB) of executed .jar file. (I believe that NetBeans uses Singleton app by default - SingleFrameView)
Will it work?

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args == null) {
            args = new String[1];
            args[0] = "Xmx512m";
        } else {
            String[] tempArgs = new String[args.length+1];
            for (int i=0; i<args.length; i++) {
            tempArgs[i] = args[i];
            }
            tempArgs[tempArgs.length-1] = "Xmx512m";
            args = tempArgs;
        }
        launch(MyApp.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: It "seems" to work, but dunno if this app uses really 512MiB of heap (JVM does)

Comment: What is that launch() method?

Comment: here take a look https://appframework.dev.java.net/nonav/javadoc/AppFramework-1.03/index.html

Comment: more exactly hre : https://appframework.dev.java.net/nonav/javadoc/AppFramework-1.03/index.html

Comment: ah damn :/
Just click on "Application" in javadoc there is "launch" method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not going to work.  The heap space is set from the -Xmx parameter at JVM initialization time.  By the time you're running Java code, it's too late.

There could be an exception if the launch() method spawns a *new* JVM, but nothing I see indicates that that is the case.

Comment: When I check in profiler JVM size it says 512 MiB.
So what does it mean?
Application resized JVM size ...
But it still will be able to use only 128 MiB of heap?

Comment: And other thing, .class bytecode files are "launched" after resizing JVM ... hmm